# Which are limits of Community version of the eZ Publish CMS?

Tags: symfony, content-management-system, ezpublish

I am currently looking for informations about eZ Publish Community version and its limits to develop a public portal.
Furthermore:

1. Can I use Oracle database? Should I prefer [ezoracle](https://github.com/ezsystems/ezoracle) to any Symfony extension?
2. Can I integrate an antivirus solution? If yes which one?
3. Can I use 2 different instances, one to write and export contents, and another one to import and update contents?
4. Which newsletter system do you suggest?
5. Is back-end IE8 and IE9 compatible?
6. Can I (de)activate contact forms on demand?
7. Can I integrate a more powerful anti-spam solution than visual CAPTCHA? (ex: reCAPTCHA)
8. Can the webmaster modify layout elements, such as logos, bannes, aso.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5):

1. Latest community version is using Doctrine DBAL (through new stack) which supports Oracle. But so far there is no information that someone tried it as the Doctrine support is quite new. ezoracle extension is a legacy extension which might be used but not if new stack is being utilised.
2. Anti-virus solutions are not something that makes sense to integrate with CMS-es. Those are either client software (CMS runs on web servers) or server side software which is installed on the web server and monitors uploaded files.
3. You probably describe a content staging kind of setup for which there is no out-of-the-box solution. But the CMS is quite flexible and some solution could be possible to develop.
4. Solid and integrated one is the cjw_newsletter, but its legacy based. There is nothing similar in the new stack, there might be some Symfony based bundles that could be integrated but would require some development effort. Depends on the integration needed. If not much integration is needed external services are an option
5. Legacy admin interface is, for the new editor UI which is under development at the moment I am not sure what will be the oldest IE supported. IE8 probably not, maybe just with graceful degradation.
6. If you mean legacy collected info based forms yes. You can hide the node of the forms for example. In new stack there are no similar implementation yet.
7. Yes, although it would probably require some web development knowledge. If you use legacy collected info forms you can try to install some of the existing legacy extension that deal with that (e.g. http://projects.ez.no/recaptcha) but to do it in new stack (Symfony based) you will probably need to dig deeper with Symfony Forms and custom controllers or find and integrate bundles that implement this
8. This depends on how the front-end is implemented. If done properly it should be possible, yes

For more detailed help feel free to use the community forum: http://share.ez.no/forums/ez-publish-5-platform